# How to compare the slopes of two regression lines?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Assume that you have two numpy arrays: `blue_y` and `light_blue_y` such as:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
blue_y = np.array([0.94732871, 0.85729212, 0.86039587, 0.89169027, 0.90817473, 0.93606619, 0.93890423, 1., 0.97783521, 0.93035495])
light_blue_y = np.array([0.81346023, 0.72248919, 0.72406021, 0.74823437, 0.77759055, 0.81167983,  0.84050726, 0.90357904, 0.97354455, 1. ])

blue_m, blue_b = np.polyfit(x, blue_y, 1)
light_blue_m, light_blue_b = np.polyfit(x, light_blue_y, 1)
```

After fitting linear regression lines to these two numpy arrays I get the following slopes:

```
>>> blue_m
0.009446010787878795
>>> light_blue_m
0.028149985151515147
```

[image]

How to compare these two slopes and show that they are statistically different from each other or not?

Comment: How would you do it without Python? Figure out the way and then implement it in  Python.

Comment: Your question has, at this point, nothing to do with programming.  You're asking for a statistical test that might be appropriate to a purpose you have not specified.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking which statistical test is appropriate and will that test be using only the two slopes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

x=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
blue_y = np.array([0.94732871, 0.85729212, 0.86039587, 0.89169027, 0.90817473, 0.93606619, 0.93890423, 1., 0.97783521, 0.93035495])
light_blue_y = np.array([0.81346023, 0.72248919, 0.72406021, 0.74823437, 0.77759055, 0.81167983,  0.84050726, 0.90357904, 0.97354455, 1. ])
```

For simplicity we can try to see the difference. If they had the same constant and the same slope that should become visible in the linear regression.

```
y = blue_y-light_blue_y
# Let create a linear regression
mod = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(x))
res = mod.fit()
```

With Output

```
print(res.summary())
```

Output

```
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.647
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.603
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     14.67
Date:                Mon, 08 Feb 2021   Prob (F-statistic):            0.00502
Time:                        23:12:25   Log-Likelihood:                 18.081
No. Observations:                  10   AIC:                            -32.16
Df Residuals:                       8   BIC:                            -31.56
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.1775      0.026      6.807      0.000       0.117       0.238
x1            -0.0187      0.005     -3.830      0.005      -0.030      -0.007
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.981   Durbin-Watson:                   0.662
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.612   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.780
```

**Interpretation**:
The constant and the slope appear different so blue_y and light_blue_y have different slope and constant term.

**Alternative**:
An more traditional you could run the linear regression of both cases and run your own F-stest.

As in here:

- [https://towardsdatascience.com/fisher-test-for-regression-analysis-1e1687867259#:~:text=The%20F%2Dtest%2C%20when%20used,its%20use%20in%20linear%20regression](https://towardsdatascience.com/fisher-test-for-regression-analysis-1e1687867259#:%7E:text=The%20F%2Dtest%2C%20when%20used,its%20use%20in%20linear%20regression).
- https://www.real-statistics.com/regression/hypothesis-testing-significance-regression-line-slope/comparing-slopes-two-independent-samples/

Comment: Is this F-statistic between slopes?  What is the null hypothesis? and  sinceProb (F-statistic):            0.00502, we reject what (this depends on the null hypothesis)?

Comment: 1) For the constant in that linear regression: Ho: constant_blue_y = constant_light_blue_y. 2) For the slope, Ho: slope_blue_y = slope_light_blue_y

Comment: So this F test  has the following null hypothesis: constants and the slopes are the same. But since p-value is <=0.05, we reject the null hypothesis claim that they are statistically different from each other.

Comment: Since you subtract (blue_y-light_blue_y) , this F test  compares constants and slopes at the same time, right?

Comment: And how you get the F statistic and p_value from res?

Comment: print(res.summary()). But now you have the problems in terms of t-tests

Comment: The F-test is -->  F-statistic:                     14.67

Comment: What do you mean by "But now you have the problems in terms of t-tests "?

Comment: You could use the F-test to say that the y is significant. And you can use the t-test of the constant and the slope to know which parts are significant. In this case F-test is significant, meaning that the regression is useful. Both t-test for the constant and the slope are significant meaning that the linear regression for both cases have significant different constants and slopes.

Comment: You mean that f-test shows whether two regression lines are statistically different from each other or not. But it does not show that if they are different, this difference is caused by slope or the constant.

Comment: How can we test only the slopes of the two regression lines?

Comment: The above is telling you that they have different slopes and constants. Now you could just remove the constant on the above model. I think that will be a bit controversial. You could run separate regression for both models and focus in the slope alone. The distribution of the slope coefficient is a t-student and you know the variance, std and number of measure, you could just compare those statistically.